# how can i know how many same tags are in xml using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, tags, count, beautifulsoup

i have a xml like this:

```
<dd class='date'>
0705
</dd>
<dd class='date'>
0707
</dd>
<dd class='date'>
0710
</dd>
<dd class='date'>
0714
</dd>
```

the output i want is(i'm finding # of ):

```
4
```

is there a neat way to do this job?
any help would be great. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("xml/html content")
tags = soup.find("some_tag")
print len(tags)
```

`len(tags)` will give you total number of tags.

Comment: thank you i couldn't think about len().  you really helped me a lot :)